# What's the state-of-the-art in learing human (motion) behaviour from videos?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, inference, graphical-model, computer-vision

Dear fellow colleagues,

I’m currently working on a research project that involves predicting human behavior from video streams. Since I’m mostly working on other fields of research, and thus I’m not up to date in the field of machine learning, I thought it might be a good idea to discuss the challenge here.

**tl;tr**
What is the current state of the art in learning temporal human behavior (movements) from training data, which can include additional process knowledge?

**Introduction**

Assume that we are given a 2D color video stream from a single camera mounted on the ceiling, observing a limited indoor workplace. In this environment we observe worker(s), larger parts to be worked on and additional points of interest (such as pickup stations, PCs and trashcans). The larger parts being mostly stationary, while worker(s) move around.

**Problem statement**

Our goal is to design a system that is able to predict the worker's (actor) movement for time $t+1$ up to $t+N$ (with increasing uncertainty).

**Approach**

Our approach currently decouples image segmentation and learning. Given a working segmentation the following sketch illustrates our environment.

[image: A segmented workspace]

We discretized space into a rectangular grid (white dashed lines). 
Now we’d like to develop a behavior model for an actor that gives us probabilities for each cell the actor might be in for $t+1$. The model to be learnt should be able to incorporate the
* the current state $t$
* possible past states $t, t-1,...$. 
* Additional process knowledge: We’d like to model information about points of interest (e.g if an actor is close to the PC/Part he/she is likely to be there for a while).

We are currently assuming that probababilistic dynamic graphical models are were our research should start, but we are unsure.

**Questions**

Assuming unlimited training data (either from a simulation or hand-labelled real world data), how would learn such a behavior model? What are the state-of-the-art tools to tackle this?

Comment: This is, in some sense, a good question. But it is not a good question for this site. It is too broad to be well answered here, and what is "state of the art" will be a matter of opinion.

Comment: @gung What would be better place to ask?

Comment: I don't know. *Primarily opinion oriented* & *too broad* are supposed to be off topic anywhere in the SE system. There is a [cogsci.SE] SE site where this might be a better fit / they may be looser w/ SE's standards, but it is still a SE site. There are also other non-SE affiliated Q&A sites on the internet (eg, Reddit & Quora); I don't know what their policies are.

Comment: I do wonder whether this could be made on-topic by some thorough editing and repurposing, though it may not then be the question you intend it to be. Making this a reference-request question rather than "describe the state of the art" question might help, but you would still need to narrow the focus somewhat.

Comment: There's also a considerable likelihood that no one here knows what "state of the art" is for learning human motion from video! It sounds like you need focussed, subject-matter expertise, and stats.stackexchange isn't a fantastically huge community.

Comment: @Silverfish I'd hope to make this somehow on-topic, but it seems like sole purpose of this question is to gather some information on the SOA of a specific topic. I could propose some references to publications I find, however I feel that defeats the purpose of the question. My intentation was to gather knowledge from experts in this broad field.

Comment: Questions that seek to gather information about a general field are usually too broad to be a good fit for our Q&A format, sadly. Essentially you're asking for a summary of the current state of play, of the kind you might find in a literature review. I do wonder if you'd be better to ask for pointers towards the relevant literature if you primarily want to find out about the field in a broad way. The alternative is to ask more specifically about suggestions for your current set-up, which is what the one answer you have at the moment seems targeted at.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a [3D convoluted neural network](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~sji/papers/pdf/Ji_ICML10.pdf). Traditional 2D convoluted neural networks excel at identifying objects in images, and 3D convolution is used for identifying objects or movements also across multiple frames (i.e., time). [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv3d) offers this capability.

The one problem with 3D convolution in general is that it requires a lot of memory, so you'll probably need to do this on a cluster, like Apache Spark. I like Amazon Web Service's (AWS) EMR capability; it installs Spark for you and only requires a few button clicks. Still, EMR doesn't come with TensorFlow out of the box, so you would have to install TensorFlow yourself.

Regardless of the approach you take, you're going to need to dedicate a lot of your time. Based on experience, I would say 100-200 hours of installations and troubleshooting, probably a lot more if you don't have strong Linux/AWS skills.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that's quite a bit of work ahead. I'm planning to spend around 700h total on this, so I'm not sure that I can afford 200hours installation.